# Sharing on face book from my application

Tags: vb.net, facebook

How can I share something on Facebook, using my vb.net code.
I donot want human intervention, I just want to supply my credentials to my application and it should automatically begin to share pictures etc. with my intervention.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Facebook Share](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/share/), this is a deprecated feature but still works.